# Swift, increment a number on each button tap

Tags: swift

I have created an app where I am uploading data to a database. However, I want to assign a specific key to each entry. For example, if the user is making their first entry into db. The key name would be "Entry 1", if they make a second entry, it would be "Entry 2". This is what I tried, but its not working.

```
@IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
      var keyCounter = 0
      keyCounter = keyCounter + 1
      print("Key Counter = ",keyCounter)
}
```

Here is the output of me pressing the button 3 times. Expected output: Key Counter = 3

Actual output:

[image]

I know that whenever I press the button its re-initializing the value of the counter to 0. I am not sure what the best way to approach this is. Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make `keyCounter` a property of the class.

Comment: `keyCounter` is local (it exists only between `{` of `Any) {` and the closing `}`. it's created each time, and initiliazed to 0 each time. make that variable a property of your class instead.

Comment: And if it is not the first time the user enters data the property should be initialized to the number of entries in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {

  var keyCounter = 0

  @IBAction func doSomething(_ sender: Any) {
    keyCounter = keyCounter + 1
    print("Key Counter = ",keyCounter)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I took what you did, and added my own twist to it. I pretty much save each increment into an online database along with the other information of course. That way I can keep track of how many entries are in the database, and increment by 1 + the max number for each new entry.